# Problem with EEPROM data corruption during power failure

Tags: microcontroller, eeprom, emc

I recently found a problem with the EEPROM of a PIC16F877A which is used to control the speed of a DC motor. The drive is supposed to work on the last set speed even if the power fails. Sometimes (but not always) after the power failure the set speed (which is read from EEPROM) is not same as the last set speed. Usually when this problem happens the value is changed to default EEPROM value 255, but not always- there aresome random values as well.

What might be the possible causes?

Comment: Power dropping too low before the write finishes.

Comment: Does your controller have brown out detection? That can help prevent this situation.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams have thought about the power dropping. But there is a voltage stabilizer which cuts off the supply if the mains drop below 170v. Also I would like to know how to make the system independent of the spikes in the mains ,as the highest supply voltage in the system is only 12v.

Comment: @jippie It has BOD and Its already enabled.

Comment: You don't want to cut off the supply, you want to perform an orderly shutdown. Including not writing to EEPROM after a certain point.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume you have some sort of a linear regulator that feeds your PIC. That regulator probably has lots of headroom (say it has 12V input and 3.3V output). The regulator will work fine in spite of the input being only 8V, for example.

You need to choose this cut-off point and feed it to a comparator that produces a logic signal called Power Good (PG). This signal will go off long *before* the regulator fails to regulate and the BOD kicks in.

Whenever PG is absent, you shouldn't be doing any EEPROM writes.

You should also store the setpoint with some check value. A simple scheme is use the [1s complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) of speed. For example, for 0x88 speed, the 1s complement is 0x77. In C:

```
typedef struct {
  uint8_t speed;
  uint8_t speed_complement;
} SetpointSlot;
```

If a setpoint slot has invalid check value, you simply ignore it.

You should be storing an even multiple SetpointSlots - at least two. If your EEPROM is paged, the slots must not cross pages, and they must be spread across two pages (or more pages if they don't all fit on two pages). With 2 setpoints, you'll have each on its own page, for example.

When starting up:

1. Iterate the slots. Use the first valid one you encounter (where `speed == ~speed_complement`).
2. If no valid slots are found, use the defualt value.

When storing a new value, you would do the following:

1. Recall the currently used setpoint slot.
2. Erase the next setpoint slot (next in a round-robin fashion, alternating pages).
3. Write the new setpoint there.
4. Verify the written values. If they're wrong, zero them out to ensure they'll stay wrong, select the next setpoint slot and go to 1.
5. Zero-out (not erase) the current setpoint slot - but only if it's not the same slot as where the new value got stored. That could be the case if you had two slots and one of them was in a "bad" area of eeprom.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand how EEPROMs work.

The initial values of a cleared EEPROM page are 0xFFs.  During writes you can set any 1 bit to a 0.  You can do this setting a byte (or even a bit) at a time, but once a bit is 0, you can't set back to 1 without erasing the *whole page*.

Many EEPROM access libraries hide this complexity, and will spot under the covers when a bit needs to be set from a 0 to a 1, and drive a page erase.  This takes time, and if there is a power off event during the process, you will be left with either a partially or fully erased page.

From the symptoms, I suspect you might just be writing to a fixed EEPROM location, and under the covers are getting erases when you do updates.

This has two problems:

- During power off, you may be in the middle of a write, so data is corrupted.
- Pages have a limit on the number of times they can be erase (10K IIRC for the 16F877) and depending on the frequency of your writes, you might hit this quite quickly.

Some higher level libraries instead provide a basic value storage system, which spreads the actual storage location over the whole of the available FLASH memory.  These typically use flag bits to indicate which parts of the page are in use / have been discarded.  (Discard is 0, so this can always be done without a page erase.) These will typically use at least 2 pages, to ensure integrity across updates.

The wear leveling will lead to greatly increased lifetime of the part, and should avoid the issues you are seeing.

Some PICs have High Endurance Flash as detailed in this appnote [Using the PIC16F1XXX High-Endurance Flash (HEF) Block](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00001673A.pdf)

Alternatively, look at cheap I2C connected FRAMs.  These allow virtually unlimited writes, without page clears.  You could then just have two fields, and alternate which is updated, writing an invalid value to the old field once the write to the new field is complete.  On restart you then just use the first non-invalid value.